# How to fix error while generate an upload key and keystore?

Tags: android-studio, google-play

It is my first time to upload an app to google play. when I tried to upload APK file I got that Error [image] I tried to fix it by **generate an upload key and keystore** I followed all the steps in here https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing  but I got that error [image] what is the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

See if there is something running in the window that's in the bottom (TODO, Terminal,logcat).

If there is; try to stop it.
After that sign it again.

(Also, if that doesn't work, try reopening the project or "invalidate cache and restart" under Files menu)
The problem should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with latest android studio, change to another version, dolphin, will solve this problem